# how to find an item in c# list

Tags: c#, list, find

```
    public class LIST
{

    public double num;
    public double longi;
    public double ux;
    public double vy;
}



  public static List<LIST> LIST1= new List<LIST>();



  LIST L1 = new LIST(); 

  L1.ux= // I take l1.ux from stream reader by reading a file  and made this 
  for 
  L1.vy=..      the other parameters 
  L1.longi=..
 L1.num=....
 LIST1.Add(L1)
```

Here my problem is ı made a list that contains 4 parameters. But ı want to find just one parameter value for instance L1.num how can I take this value from a list?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please clarify. Are you trying to get from `LIST1` for each item only the `num` property`?  or do you want to find items in `LIST1` where the `num` property equals some value?

Comment: Do you want to find only 1 instance in LIST1 which have its num = L1.num?

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexOfLISTObject = 1 //you need to know which object from LIST1 you want to use
var numParamOfLISTObject = LIST1[indexOfLISTObject].num;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Don't name your object LIST. It will create readability issues down the line for you. Name the object what a particular item in your list will represent.
2. To access a particular property from an item in list you can do following

`List l1 = new list();`

```
    //Add items ...
   //Print property from particular index
    Console.WriteLine(l1[index].propertyname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the paremeters inside a list one by one.

in your example you want the parameter num.

List parameterNum = new List();

parameterNum = l1.Select(x => x.Num).ToList();

parameterNum has now the list of Num from l1 list.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to **find/search** for a particular value, you could also use `System.Linq`. For example if you would like to find a member where `num is set to 2`, you could do this:

`LIST1.Where(item=>item.num==2).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

According my Understanding If you want to Get objects that contain with specific parameter
then you can use this code

```
 public static List<LIST> LIST1= new List<LIST>();

 LIST L1 = new LIST();

 var SearchedValue= List1.where(x=>x.num==L1.num).tolist();
```

if you want just L1.num value then you can use this line (if searched record will 1 then you should use this)

```
  var SearchedValue= List1.where(x=>x.num==L1.num).FirstOrDefault().num;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

LIST1[index].propertyname  //index is index of list element and propertyname is the name of property you want to access